# Cache browser images if no file extension provided

Tags: caching, browser, jpeg

When a browser requests a jpg and the server returns the data but not as a reference to a jpg file but rather sends the jpg data itself, is it possible for the browser to cache the data?

For example:

http://www.somewebsite.com/image/abc

This uri returns jpg data. Is there some way to get the browser to cache the data it receives to avoid having to request it again?

Answer (score 0):

I just attempted to debug your example but received an `Account Suspended. Webmaster, please, contact support.` page!

So as I am working blind can I suggest researching the `header('Expires: SOME DATA HERE')` function in PHP (I assume you are using PHP).

If the solution does not lie there you can also use .htaccess to set the headers using

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

This example taken from http://www.robertwent.com/blog/servers-and-hosting/45-set-expires-headers-in-htaccess

Ultimately it is the headers that tell the browser how you advise the content is cached. What the browsers actually does can sometimes be surprising.